# Linux apt-get upgrade wifi Disconnecting

Tags: kali-linux, raspberry-pi, upgrade

After installing Kali Linux on my Raspberry Pi 4, I ran the command `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Before it was done, the wifi connection disconnected and reconnected again.

Is this a normal behavior or is there something that I should be worried about?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek: “behaviour” is correct in British English, and [we have a policy against changing British English spelling to American English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23869/271976 "What should the standard spelling be – British or US?"). … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  OTOH, I tend to change “wifi” to “Wi-Fi”, based on [ref1](https://www.bkacontent.com/quick-guide-correctly-writing-seo-and-general-internet-terms "A Quick Guide to Correctly Writing General Internet Terms"), [ref2](https://www.tourtech.com/2019/01/how-do-you-spell-wifi/ "The Great Spelling Debate: Wi-Fi, WiFi, Wifi, or Wi-fi?") and [ref3](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41180/how-do-you-spell-wifi-wi-fi-wifi "How do you spell wifi / Wi-Fi / WiFi? — this is a Stack Exchange site.").

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica'  From the link you quote in accepted answer: "Does SOFU have an accepted standard on language and spelling? Which is it?" "For bodies, no.". Note that I did not edit just that, I edited mainly other things and that in passing just because my automated checking tool flagged it. If you feel so strongly about that minor change, feel free to edit my edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debian (on which Kali is based upon) usually start services on installation and restarts services on upgrade (unless just a reload is possible). The reason a restart is done is to ensure the new binary replaces the former binary. Just reloading a configuration, which is supposed to be without visible effect, would also require the daemon to serialize its current state to some file, re-exec itself and reload the previous state: not that many can do this, so it's not often available. There are other distributions which choose to usually not restart to have less immediate disruption.

If packages such as *network-manager*, *wpasupplicant* or *hostapd* and probably many others, are upgraded, depending on your specific configuration, their `postinst` script will restart the corresponding daemon.

This would explain your Wifi connection dropping and coming back.

As an illustration, here's an excerpt for *wpasupplicant*'s `postinst` for Kali's [`wpasupplicant_2.9-6_arm64.deb`](https://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/w/wpa/) (current version as of writing this):

```
# Automatically added by dh_installsystemd/12.7.3
if [ "$1" = "configure" ] || [ "$1" = "abort-upgrade" ] || [ "$1" = "abort-deconfigure" ] || [ "$1" = "abort-remove" ] ; then
        if [ -d /run/systemd/system ]; then
                systemctl --system daemon-reload >/dev/null || true
                if [ -n "$2" ]; then
                        _dh_action=restart
                else
                        _dh_action=start
                fi
                deb-systemd-invoke $_dh_action 'wpa_supplicant.service' >/dev/null || true
        fi
fi
# End automatically added section
```

It will start the service if it wasn't an upgrade, or restart it for an upgrade.

If you're upgrading from remote, to stay on the safe side and avoid chicken-and-egg problems related to connectivity during the upgrade you should probably run the upgrade inside tools like [`screen`](https://manpages.debian.org/screen/screen.1#DESCRIPTION) or [`tmux`](https://manpages.debian.org/tmux/tmux.1#DESCRIPTION).